# Uncountable or countable

Tags: real-analysis, density-function

For each $t\in R$, let $E_t$ be a subset for $R$. Suppose that is $s<r$ then $E_s$ is a proper subset of $E_r$ . Must be $\bigcup_{t\in R}{E_t}$ be uncountable?

Comment: What is $r$? Or did you mean $s < t$?

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider the set of rationals less than a given real. That is, take
$$E_r=\{q\in\Bbb{Q}:q<r\}.$$

Comment: Thanks, i supposed that, this problem was related with the completion of the rational numbers to get the real number but I'm not sure about that, thanks again

Comment: @Juan You are right. To show $E_r$ is strictly increasing, it is sufficient to see that for any reals $r<s$ we have a rational $q$ such that $r<q<s$.